# How to add div with class after 12 loop using php ?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a bootstrap 3 columns with 12 rows using following php `for` loop. But it's showing all the data in one column. How can I make this `for` loop result in bootstrap 3 columns ( col-md-4 ) ?

**Php For Loop:**

```
<?php
    for ( $x = 1; $x <= 36; $x++) {
        if( $x % 12 == 0 || $x == 1 ) {
            echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
        }
    ?> 
        <div class="checkbox form-inline">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="ch_name[]" value="ch<?php echo $x; ?>">CH<?php echo $x; ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="ch_for[]" value="" placeholder="Channel details" class="form-control ch_for">
        </div>

        <?php if( $x % 12 == 0 ) {
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper code is:

```
<?php
    for ( $x = 1; $x <= 36; $x++) {
        // proper condition
        if( $x % 12 == 1 ) {
            echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
        }
    ?> 
        <div class="checkbox form-inline">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="ch_name[]" value="ch<?php echo $x; ?>">CH<?php echo $x; ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="ch_for[]" value="" placeholder="Channel details" class="form-control ch_for">
        </div>

        <?php if( $x % 12 == 0 ) {
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```